# dispatch_async Nested Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I am using dispatch_async method to execute task in main queue. But it causing retain cycle:

Following is the code snippet:

```
self.test = ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", self);
        });
   };
```

I am not able to get properly why it is creating retain cycle. As My controller does not have ownership of dispatch_async block.

Comment: Property `test` retains the closure and the closure contains a reference to `self`  It doesn't matter that that reference is itself in a block

Answer (score 1):

Try using `weakSelf`:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.test = ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf);
    });
};
```

Comment: but then `self` could get deallocated between the running of the outer block and the (asynchronous) running of the inner block, which may not be what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the outer block to retain `self`, but want the inner block to be able to keep `self` alive once dispatched, maybe something like this:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.test = ^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", strongSelf);
        });
    }
};
```